# why I can use Stack<Double> but not Stack<double>?

Tags: java

Why I can't use `Stack<double>`?

Is there anything special about the types Double other than boxing?

As simple as that. Thank you

Comment: This question is hardly a dupe of that one

Answer (score 4):

`double` is primitive

`Double` is wrapper class.

And `Generics` in Java works with class (object) not primitives.

Comment: You should vote to close this question as a duplicate rather than answering it again...

Comment: @jahroy oops...!! didn't thought about it when the question pops infront of me. will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Generics in java work on any type of object (e.g., `Double`). They are not supported for primitives (e.g., `double`).